# fabfile.py not working: No module named Crypto

Tags: python, django, fabric

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/18/starting-a-django-16-project-the-right-way/), and reached the section on using Fabric to deploy django projects. However when I run my fabfile.py I get [this error](https://github.com/ng150716/error/blob/master/error). And [here](https://github.com/ng150716/error/blob/master/fabfile.py) is my fabfile.py. For what i can deduce the Crypto library is missing, by I've tried pip install Crypto and still get the same error. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Try `pip install pycrypto`.

Comment: Yea, according to pip freeze it's already installed, but I tried it still. And got the same error.

Answer (score 10):

It could be that when you installed it, it didn't compile all the necessary files. Try re-installing again.  Make sure you see no errors, if you do you might be missing some development files/headers.

```
pip uninstall pycrypto
pip install pycrypto
```

You can just test it from the python shell:

```
python
```

Then:

```
>>> import Crypto
```

If you don't see any errors you are good.

If for some reason the module got compiled as crypto instead of Crypto on the Mac you can try:

```
>> import crypto
>> import sys
>> sys.modules['Crypto'] = crypto
```

Comment: I had this case issue on my system. I had tried `pip install Crypto` then when that didn't work (`import Crypto` failed) I tried `pip install pycrypto`. Same problem. So I uninstalled both `Crypto` and `pycrypto`, and then just installed `pycrypto`. That resolved the case issue, and `import Crypto` worked fine thereafter. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Fabric. pycrypto isn't listed as a requirement, and so it's not installed...

Comment: @Cerin that's why you downvote? the requirements.txt file varies depending on your env

Comment: while this fixes it in the shell, it doesn't work for me as I'm getting this error within Django's framework calling Crypto.